# Are Push Notifications tokens unique to Mac & iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, macos, apple-push-notifications, token

By that I mean: If you have an app running on both platform, can you be sure that a given token on iOS isn't attributed to Mac? I'm pretty sure this isn't something we can "know" (Apple internal) and I shouldn't assume it, but I'm really curious what happens if you (by mistake) send an "iOS" Push (intended for your iOS App) to a Mac token. Could it reach another iOS user?! I guess potentially...

Imagine the following case (simplified):

- You know you have to send a push to the token "foo" to your Mac app.
- You mistakenly send a push to "foo" on your iOS app.
- I hope it would land in void land / you'd get an error back from APNS but I guess it might also land on a "random" user of your iOS app, which is not the user intended (on the Mac app)

Answer (score 3):

Sending a push notification requires an SSL certificate from Apple that is bound to your iOS or Mac application. Therefore it can not happen that a notification for an iOS app is sent to a Mac app.

Comment: @StuFFmc: Perhaps I do not understand your question correctly. But you don't send a notification to a token on an iOS or Mac app. You send a notification to the Apple Push Notification service (gateway.push.apple.com) using a SSL connection and the SSL certificate that you got from Apple. This certificate controls to which application the notification is sent. Since you have different certificates for iOS and Mac apps, it is not mistakenly sent to the wrong platform.

Comment: I confirm: You still don't understand the question :-) It's hard for me to explain it more than the way I added the bullet points though. Also, I understand you're not "directly" sending a push to a device. Thanks for you time though.

Answer (score 1):

From the following quote it doesn't seem possible that the same device token will be assigned to both an iOS device and a Mac (or to two iOS devices or to two Macs), since device tokens contain device IDs, and device IDs should be unique (otherwise they wouldn't be very useful IDs).

> Every notification that a provider sends to APNs for delivery to a device must be accompanied by the device token it obtained from an application on that device. APNs decrypts the token using the token key, thereby ensuring that the notification is valid. It then uses **the device ID contained in the device token to determine the destination device** for the notification. 
>   ([Source](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ApplePushService.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH100-SW9))

Comment: And what makes you think Device IDs are unique between devices? I guess so as well, but I'm not 100% sure. That said, thanks for that source. I missed that one somehow.